# JS - Getting alert multiple times while long polling on success?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I was following a video tutorial on how to do long polling, and it seems I got it done, but I'm having one issue, for some reason, though I get one response from server, my alert shows up 3-6 times. I thought "success" only happens once if we got one response.

2nd question is, how can I make this javascript code cancel the ajax call every 30 seconds, and restart it? I've put in setInterval with .abort() in there while experimenting with no luck, probably wrong placement.

Thank you for the wisdom and help!

```
var timestamp = null;
var imp = null;
var annk = null;
function waitForMsg(){
    $.ajax( 
    {  
        type: "GET",  
        url: "/test?timestamp=" + timestamp + "&imp=" +imp + "&annk=" +annk,
        dataType : 'json',  
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) 
        {
                            alert("hello");
                if(data.annkr > "0"){
                    $("#myidone").css("background-color", "#cccccc");
                }else{
                    $("#myidone").css("background-color", "#cccccc");
                }
                if(data.impr > 0){
                    $("#myidtwo").css("background-color", "#000000");
                }else{
                    $("#myidtwo").css("background-color", "#000000");
                }
            annk = data.annkr;
            imp = data.impr;
            timestamp = data.timestamp;
            setTimeout('waitForMsg()',2000);    
        }
    });
}   

$(document).ready(function(){
    waitForMsg();
});
```

I read stuff on Stackoverflow about readystates, but how do I make sure it's ready only once and does it after it's ready?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be seeing the alert multiple times due to the setTimeout() in your success function, you keep calling the waitForMsg() function. Just a guess.

To abort the request you could do something like this:

```
var timer = null;
function waitForMessage() {
  var req = $.ajax(YOUR_CODE);

  // The 30 second timeout
  timer = setTimeout(function() {
    req.abort();
    waitForMessage();
  }, 30000);
}
```

Or slightly better maybe:

```
function waitForMsg() {
  $.ajax({
    timeout: 30000,
    error: function(err) {
      if(err === 'timeout') {
        waitForMsg();
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the 2nd method was best and easy to use. Works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

If the code is exactly the one you posted, there's no reason to show the alert more than 1 and then after 2s for the rescheduling.

Can you make a jsFiddle for that showing the problem?

The second question is more interesting. You can use the `timeout` option in the `.ajax` call and then, in the error handler, just reschedule the call.

My personal suggestion is to refactor your code to use the new JQuery Ajax style base on `.done` `.fail` and `.always`.

And that setTimeout should be written as `setTimeout(waitForMsg,2000)`. Using the string parameter you evaluate that string instead of just calling the function and it's a performance penalty (so small that's hardly noticeable but that is ).

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I changed the setTimeout to the method you showed without the apostrophes. The code is exactly as I posted, but for some reason, this morning I woke up and it's not doing it anymore.. I will be looking into the .done, .fail, and .always now, I haven't seen those yet. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you should use setInterval instead of setTimeout, using this approach if your ajax call fails, you will forcelly abort the loop.

You could also, cancel or change the timeout timings depending on the usage of your service for network resource sanity.